# How good are Hydromatic sump pumps?

Tags: sump-pump

I just replaced a Hydromatic D-A1 with date 4-98. It was in service most likely from 1998 till I replaced it here in May 2021. 23 years on duty.  I’ve owned the house since 2007 and it was there. It looked old as hell the day we moved in.  Its watch has ended.

However, the pump is still working fine; that’s for sure. It’s just the switch failed “on” recently.  I discovered it sucking air and intermittent water one day, running constantly in a nearly dry pit. I don’t know how long it was like that, but I assume less than a day.  But it could have been a couple.  It’s pretty quiet.

Thinking of servicing the switch and keeping the pump on hand as a last resort backup I can install in the middle of the night if for some crazy reason the battery backup fails or isn’t cutting it.

I hate to throw away such an impressive unit!

[image: Picture of Hydromatic D-A1 sump pump]

Comment: Totally opinion based on one hand I would say what it failed , on the other hand oh my gosh you got 20+ years of service that’s awesome. Then I look at a photo that shows a pump that has rarely seen water (or compared to every sump I have seen after a year of actual use).

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but it sounds like you are saying it has rarely seen water?  No man. Not the case. This has seen a LOT of water. I wiped the label off - maybe that’s why you think it is clean?  I had serious water issues where rainwater would make this run a lot during rains.  This was running multiple times daily for over 2 decades.

Comment: Net dad I have replaced dozens of pumps with less than 1/2 the age of yours and it looks clean but the question is off topic because it is opinion based if it has seen lots of use it is a great pump. The pumps I see that have been sitting in water for 10 years are in much worse shape. Service it and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

I would put it in sufficient water and test it. Then I would fit a new switch depending on the result.

As you seem to be able to cope if it is not working for a day or so then getting a replacement if it fails is not an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I already know it works. It was working when I removed it.